# How to Model a list inside a sequence

Tags: xml, xsd, modeling

How can I model something like with an XSD?

```
<element>
 <foo>2</foo>
 <bar>5</bar>
 <bar>5</bar>
</element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When learning about XSD, it is always a good idea to enlist the help of a tool. For example, I would suggest to have such a tool generate for you the XSD based on the snippet. It may look something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="element">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="foo" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="bar" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

You could then see if that matches your needs by tweaking your XML, then validate again. Tweak your XSD; maybe look for what each <xsd:XXX/> tag does, particularly sequence, choice, etc. It should speed up your learning curve....

Comment: If forget to set maxOccurs="unbounded". Thx for your help